# typing right to left

Tags: textarea, right-to-left

I'm trying to create a textarea that types right to left to make it easier for people that write in arabic. I also use tinymce.

Here is my code that has the arabic textarea

```
<p>content arabic<textarea id='content_arabic_add_$id_page' name='content_arabic_add_$id_page' lang='ar' dir='rtl' style='width:100%;'></textarea></p>
```

Comment: I pasted that snippet into a fiddle and it seems to be typing from Right to left? http://jsfiddle.net/ZYZ5A/

Comment: Do you think it might not be working because of the tinymce? I added the theme_advanced_buttons1: "ltr, rtl", to the tinymce